# JavaScript function execution scope

Tags: javascript, function

In JavaScript, it is said that functions are executed using the scope that was in effect when the function was defined. It has nothing to do with the scope in effect when the function is called.

What exactly does it mean?

Comment: may this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 2):

The output of the following is A because `foo` is *defined* in the scope of `function a`, so the variable `data` that it uses is the one that is also defined in the scope of `function a`.

It doesn't output B even though the function was *called* in the scope of `function b` where `data = "B"`.

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
  var data = "global";

  function a() {
    var data = "A";
    function foo() {
       document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data;
    }
    return foo;
  }

  function b() {
    var data = "B";
    var func = a();
    func();
  }

  b();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Global variables are on every scope chain
var global = 'global'

// Function variables are only on a function's scope chain
function bar() {
  var fn = 'fn';

  // foo called from here where fn is avaialble as a local variable
  foo(); // undefined

  return function() {
    alert(fn)
  }
}


function foo() {
  // foo can access global because it's on its scope chain
  alert(global);

  // Can't access fn because it's on bar's scope chain
  // so returns undefined
  alert(typeof fn);    
}

// the function returned by bar has access to fn
var f = bar(); // global

f(); // fn
```